# cmake and llvm-config config

Tags: cmake, llvm-clang

I have multiple versions of llvm installed on my Unix machine, I am building a CMake project that requires LLVM50 and lower but setting the CMake LLVM_CONFIG path it finds LLVM60.

Is there a way to nudge CMake in finding the right LLVM version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't write how these versions are accessible to your commandline (e.g. is Clang 3.9 executed as `clang-3.9` or do you have to export its `bin` directory in the `$PATH` environment variable?)

Once the desired LLVM/Clang version is in my `$PATH`, what I usually do is to use the `llvm-config` for the specific version I'm interested in to pass `cmake` variable values (especially `LLVM_DIR`), e.g.

```
cmake \
  -GNinja \
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
  -DLLVM_DIR="$(llvm-config --cmakedir)" \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
[...]
```

If the `--cmakedir` option is not available in the LLVM version that you want, use something like `$(llvm-config --prefix)/share/llvm/cmake/)` instead (or wherever the cmake dir with the definitions is).

Also, adjust `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to the correct executable name as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `$PATH` variable in Linux like:

`export $PATH=<path_to_llvm_bin_folder>:$PATH`

You can also place this in your .bashrc file, if you always use a specific version of llvm.